# How to apply a theme generated from Material 3 Theme builder website to the project in Angular 17.2.0?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material3

I am using Angular 17.2.0, I wish to apply custom theming to my Material 3 UI (Experimental). I generated a theme from https://m3.material.io/theme-builder. I exported the theme which gives me a bunch of CSS files, I included the theme.css file which `@imports` all the other files. I could not find any documentation in relation to how to use user-defined theme, all the documentation is regarding how to use pre-defined palettes or to set primary, accent color for material 2.

Following is the code of my current styles.scss file:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use '@angular/material-experimental' as matx;

$dark-theme: matx.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: dark,
    primary: matx.$m3-green-palette
  ),
  density: (
    scale: -1
  )
)); 

*{
  @include mat.all-component-themes($dark-theme);
}

html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

I tried including the theme.css file which @imports all the other files, searched for documentation on m3.material.io and https://material.angular.io/ but couldn't come up with an answer to my problem.

Edit: I have also tried it with and without `@include mat.core()`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [demo app](https://ng-comp-devapp.web.app/) styles : https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/dev-app/theme-m3.scss

You're at least missing `@include mat.core();`

Comment: I'll mention it in my question but I was trying to remove and add mat.core() as well. But that didn't help. Also the app you linked isn't using the themes generated from material theme builder but the one which are pre-defined palettes